# How to share the same options array along 2 Materials UI multiple autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const [goodMovies, setGoodMovies] = React.useState([]);
const [badMovies, setBadMovies]] = React.useState([]);

<div className={classes.root}>
    <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Good Movies"
          />
        )}

        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setGoodMovies(newValue)
        }}
    />

    <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Bad Movies"
          />
        )}

        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setBadMovies(newValue)
        }}
    />

</div>
```

Here, when someone has selected a film in GOOD MOVIE textfield, I do NOT want that option to appear in the BAD MOVIE options. So How to do this???

Currently, complete list is showing in both the components, irrespective whether a film has been selected in GOOD MOVIE or NOT.

Comment: In this case, you have to have two arrays instead of one `top100Films`. So like `top100GoodFilmOptions` and `top100BadFilmOptions`. And now you can remove film from `top100BadFilmOptions` when someone select it in Good Movie Textfield and vice versa.

Comment: I need both good movies and bad movies on the same page, so even after removing a film from top100BadFilmOptions, the bad movies options are not getting refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!!
I used getOptionDisabled props in the badMovies Autocomplete to disable the movies which are in the goodMovies... so that the user is NOT able to select the already selected good movies in the bad movies.